# SQL alter a column if exists

Tags: sql, if-statement, exists

I have two tables.  A and B.  I'm trying to figure out a way to add a column in my select query that returns true or false as to whether or not there exists a record in B.

```
Table A
ID     Title
1      A
2      B
3      C
4      D
5      E

Table B
ID     Detail
3      foo
4      foo
4      bar
4      barfood
```

I want to basically "SELECT ID, Title, (Exists?) FROM A" to return

```
ID     Title     Exists
1      A         False
2      B         False
3      C         True
4      D         True
5      E         False
```

Table A's ID column will always be unique.  Table B's ID column can have zero, one, or many relating back to table A's ID.  I don't care about the detail in table B, I just want to know if there is at least one record in table B that relates to table A's ID.

I'm new to SQL and I've been searching for ways to use 'if exists' or any other way to parse this out but I'm not really finding what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding a column named 'Exists' temporary then try this

```
select a.id, a.title,case when a.id=b.id then 'True' else 'False' end as Exists       
from A a left outer join B b
on a.id = b.id
```

If you've alredy added Exists column to table then

```
select a.id, a.title,Exists=(case when a.id=b.id then 'True' else 'False')      
from A a left outer join B b
on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: This definitely got me in the right direction.  I just had to add in the distinct and a little formatting and that's perfect.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more efficient ways to accomplish it, but a combination of count and a case statement will do the trick:

```
select ID, Title, 
case when 
    (select count(1) from B where ID = A.ID) = 0 then 'False'
else 'True'
end as 'Exists'
from A
```

[SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81d94/1/0)

Comment: Plus one for a combination of the earliest answer and coolest user name.

Answer (score 0):

if you left join table B then you'll get that information

```
select a.id, a.title, 
case 
  when b.id is null then 'false'
  else 'true'
end
from a
left outer join b on a.id = b.id
group by a.id, a.title
```